# Run level script - Help

Tags: shell-script, scripting, init-script, bash-script, runlevel

I want the following command to be ran, as soon as system boots.

```
glances -s -P redhat &
```

How to achieve that?

I tried writing a run level script which didn't work as expected.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Comment: Seeing that he put redhat in the command I would assume he's running linux.

Comment: @Jeight or Fedora, or CentOS or something else altogether. Which version? Is the OP using systemd or upstart? In any case, as far as I can tell, the `-P` option to glances [specifies a password](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/blob/master/docs/glances-doc.rst#command-line-options) so I doubt that is very indicative of the system used :).

Comment: If we're being specific Fedora and CentOS are distributions and not an OS. But I can pretty well bet that he is using a RedHat based distro. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put that line in `/etc/rc.local` it will get executed on startup, you might want to give a full path for the binary. This will work on [CentOS 5](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html) and [CentOS 6](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html).

FWIW, the RHEL documentation says it should be used when an init script is too complex: "easy way to perform necessary tasks like starting special services... without writing complex initialization scripts"

Answer (score 0):

Create an init script and place it in /etc/init.d. Activate it in the correct rc level.

Comment: Could you expand a bit please? Perhaps explain the format of `init` scripts and how one activates them?

Comment: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15380.html might help. It's a good tutorial on how to create init scripts.

Comment: Thanks, but I was pointing out that on the SE network, we tend to like answers with a bit more meat to them. While this points the OP in the right direction, it does not actually contain the information necessary to do what you suggest. Ideally, and answer will take info from other sources (crediting them) and include it here with a short explanation.

Comment: Adding the line in /etc/rc.local didn't help. I am trying to write an init script and if I am successful, will paste it here.

Comment: If you are able to wait to run it until login you could put the command in /etc/bashrc. That might be far easier.